# JS: Implementing custom 'Are you sure you want to leave this page' modal dialog

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I know this is probably have been discussed before, but I wonder how Facebook actually implements this feature successfully - in https://www.facebook.com/messages/new: 
When composing a message and then trying to press the 'Back' button in the browser, I get facebook's own custom dialog which verifies that I really want to leave the page.

I know I can use `beforeunload` event to bring up a native dialog, but how do I create my own custom one, like Facebook's.

I figured that one way is probably using jQuery and run an event on the entire set of links.

But how does it work for everything else (like the 'Back' button in the browser, for instance).

I figured it may have something to do with pushState control, or the fact that facebook probably uses some client side framework, and when pressing 'Back' I don't actually UNLOAD the window.

anyways, would be happy to get some info regarding this issue.

Comment: Did you figure out an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

It's just HTML, CSS and JS. In the case of a composing a message, which is really just a form, set your `beforeunload` event and check to see if any of the form fields have been filled in. If so, show your custom html. Maybe this can help you get started: http://jsbin.com/ronuyo/1/